# Is there a PHP function to combine the results of 2 arrays based off of keys?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

If I have the following arrays

```
arry1 = array(
    101 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data'
    ),
    102 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data'
    ),
    .
    .
    .
);

arry2 = array(
    101 => array(
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    ),
    102 => array(
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    ),
    .
    .
    .
);
```

and I want to change them into

```
arry3 = array(
    101 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data',
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    ),
    102 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data',
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    ),
    .
    .
    .
);
```

Is there a simple function from [php arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) to do this? If not, what do you believe would be the most efficient way to program this?

Thanks for any help,
Metropolis

**EDITED**

Sorry I updated the arrays to be the way they actually should be....array_merge_recursive gives me the following,

```
arry3 = array(
    0 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    ),
    .
    .
    .
);
```

I need the 101, and 102 to stick, and I need the data to all be in the same lower level array....

Comment: Do not use array_merge_recursive() if you have numeric keys. Arrays that are held under numeric keys (as in your case) won't be merged.

Comment: @Kamil Right, thats what im running into :). Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to add the latter array to the first. Therefore, [use this](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
array_merge_recursive(array1, array2);
```

... and it'll do exactly what you want.

**EDIT:**
As it seems, that my above solution is not entirely correct, use this:

```
<?

function array_merge_subarrays(array $array1, array $array2) {
    $resultArray = array();
    // The foreach instead of a plain for is to keep the specific values of the keys
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $subarray) {
        $resultArray[$key] = array_merge($subarray, $array2[$key]);
    }
    return $resultArray;
}

$arr1 = array(
    101 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data'
    ),
    102 => array(
        'title1' => 'data', 
        'title2' => 'data', 
        'title3' => 'data'
    )
);

$arr2 = array(
    101 => array(
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    ),
    102 => array(
        'title4' => 'data', 
        'title5' => 'data', 
        'title6' => 'data'
    )
);

print_r(array_merge_subarrays($arr1, $arr2));

/*

OUTPUTS:

Array ( 
    [101] => Array ( 
        [title1] => data
        [title2] => data
        [title3] => data
        [title4] => data
        [title5] => data
        [title6] => data
    )
    [102] => Array (
        [title1] => data 
        [title2] => data 
        [title3] => data 
        [title4] => data 
        [title5] => data 
        [title6] => data
    )
)

*/

?>
```

Comment: I would upvote this but I'm out of votes for the day... and @sirhc just took it to the next level in a race to win a green checkmark =b

Comment: @Metropolis: Yeah, I see. Updated my answer with a little self-written one ;)

Comment: @Sune Works great, and pretty efficient. Thanks a lot! So I assume there is no PHP function that handles this huh?

Comment: @Metropolis: To be honest with you, *I don't know*, but it doesn't seem so. See this as you'll know why: http://php.net/quickref.php :) ... So I suggested writing an efficient little bastard for you was easier ;)

Comment: Nice job! :) I didn't think about the renumbering.